# Why the textfield shouldChangeCharactersInRange method is not executing?

Tags: objective-c, textfield

Hi in my application I have a registration form in that I have few textfields. Along with these textfields I am using few delegate methods. The delegate methods which I am using are

1. Did Begin Editing
2. Did End Editing
3. Should Change characters in range methods

Out of these three methods only 1st and 2nd methods are  executing while editing the text-fields but 3rd method is not executing.

Please let me know the reason for this behaviour. Even I set the delegate to the textfield. If is there any problem with delegate link even 1st and 2nd methods are also won't be execute right? So please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Copy and paste the actual `shouldChangeCharacters...` method from your code into your question. Most likely you have a typo in the name.

Comment: Hi Thanks to one and all who are trying to help me. Finally i found the reason for this behaviour.That is Actually i am using category concept in my project.In that category class i have this Should Change characters in range method and the same method i have in main class also.Due to this that category class method is executing but actually required behaviour code is available in main class method due to this i did not get output. Thanks once again.

Comment: Good to hear that your question is answered, gadamsetty. Please post your solution as an answer and accept it, or delete the question, so that others know your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the reason for this behavior.That is Actually i am using category concept in my project.In that category class i have this Should Change characters in range method and the same method i have in main class also.Due to this that category class method is executing but actually required behavior code is available in main class method due to this i did not get output. Thanks.